# Spring Security login with extra field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

spring security creates a username and password as the factory setting, but I have one username and 2 passwords. How can I set this up?

Comment: may be your are looking for [this](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2018/10/passing-extra-login-fields-with-spring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authentication provider by implementing the ***AuthenticationProvider*** interface and modify it accordingly for ***2 password authentication***. The *authenticate method* returns a fully populated **Authentication** object if the authentication is successful. If **authentication** fails, it throws an exception of type **AuthenticationException**.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

 @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = auth.getName();
    String password = auth.getCredentials()
        .toString();

    if ("<username>".equals(username) && "<password>".equals(password)) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
          (username, password, Collections.emptyList());
    } else {
        throw new
          BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
    }
}

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
    return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```